# Window size store so that next time when opened it is the same as before

Tags: windows

I have a window(MDI ) create,when it is opened by application,i will increase it size by dragging,and close it.so next time if i open it,the size has to new one.Values have to be stored in INI,i know this,but how to get the exact coordinates so that it can used later to open it

Answer (score 0):

The window object should have the following properties:

- Top
- Left
- Height
- Width

Comment: And WindowState, if the window can be minimised.